# How do I fix sagging sofa back and seat cushions on a leather couch?

Tags: cleaning

Around 18 months ago, I purchased a VRETA sofa bed - Mjuk black from IKEA for $1000.

I have used this couch quite a bit either for watching TV, playing on my laptop or reading a book. As a result, the back and seat cushions are quite saggy and it's not as comfortable leaning back. Same thing with the seat cushions. Both sets of cushions have noticeable wrinkles. Fortunately, there is no tearing of that sort.

I also have two leather care products from IKEA (A leather cleaner and a leather cream bottle). I'm not sure how much either of them would help though.

Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Here is a link to the couch

http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/20109805/

Comment: As DMoore said, contact Ikea. Did a quick search and see there's a 10 year warranty that covers everything except the leather. Here's the warranty doc http://www.ikea.com/ms/en_US/img/customer_service/VRETA_warranty.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If this is only a year old I would think it would still be under warranty from IKEA.  I would call them and ask what you should do.

Normally the manufacturer will send you some foam (or whatever) inserts.  Then you would add them to the cushions.  If there is no easy way to insert the inserts then the manufacturer might have someone with expertise visit your house to help.

If you want to fix this yourself and want nothing to do with IKEA then figure out what is in your couch and get more of it.  Then cut open the couch where need be and staple/sew it back together.  You are dealing with leather so this is not easy at all.

Answer (score 0):

Research the type of foam used and buy yourself on Ebay.

Then insert it - alternatively you can buy a different foam and surround the current cushion with it.

I found some relevant guides here (one has pictures)

http://www.nabru.co.uk/blog/how-to-fix-a-sagging-sofa/

http://loveoffamilyandhome.net/2014/02/saggy-couch-solutions.html

Comment: Your answer would be a lot more helpful if you summarized (but avoid plagiarizing) the content of the guides you linked to in your answer.

Comment: Im not sure I would recommend buying on Ebay, always check to see what the manufacturer offers first. I know that at http://www.newmanandbright.co.uk they have special options for people to fix these things.